# Error with importing pandas in python3 'TypeError: descriptor '__subclasses__' of 'type' object needs an argument'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, importerror

the command `import pandas as pd` in Python 3.5.2 gives an error :

```
'TypeError: descriptor '__subclasses__' of 'type' object needs an argument'
```

This happens only with Python3 and Python 2 imports pandas just fine. I searched the error code and applied the suggestions others provided, which didn't work for me.

Comment: what's your python environment

Answer (score 3):

Update your python to 3.5.3+ version. It starts with the 0.25.x pandas series.

From the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html):

> Officially Python 3.5.3 and above, 3.6, and 3.7.

Comment: Somehow it took a lot of steps to upgrade my python3 but I finally made it. Now it works, thank you.